# Having trouble reading string in if statement

Tags: java, android

I am able to covert an integer array to a string.

```
    if (tempArray1[6] == true) {
        num[0] = 1;
    }
    if (tempArray2[6] == true) {
        num[1] = 1;
    }
    if (tempArray3[6] == true) {
        num[2] = 1;
    }
    if (tempArray4[6] == true) {
        num[3] = 1;
    }

    Number = Arrays.toString(num).replace(",", "");
    Log.e("NUMBER", "number is :" + Number);
```

The outcome of the Log statement reads

11-07 10:03:17.577: ERROR/NUMBER(990): number is :[1 1 0 0]

Now i try to use an if statement to check for the possible outcome:

```
    if (Number == "1 1 0 0") {
        Log.e("NOTIFY", "1100");
       notificationMessage = "Input Wire 1 and 2";
    }
```

But for some reason it never find this if statement to be true, even though log says that Number is 1100. Can someone please help me in being able to read the value of Number(string) in the if statement.

Answer (score 2):

You have to compare Strings using equals() and numbers using == 
and what you do here is neither:

```
if (Number == "1 1 0 0")
```

Answer (score 2):

You are missing `[` and `]` in `"1 1 0 0"` and you are using `==` instead of `.equals` to compare strings.

It should be:

```
if (Number.equals("[1 1 0 0]"))
```

Answer (score 2):

Three things that might help you (the third is only a convention, but an important one):

1. Use `equals` method to compare objects (and strings are objects). e.g. - `if (Number.equals("1 1 0 0") )`
2. You forgot the `[` and `]` - `if (Number.equals("[1 1 0 0]") )`
3. Start variable names with lower case: `if (number.equals("[1 1 0 0]") )`

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it's will be more productive code:

```
        StringBuilder resultNumber = new StringBuilder();
        if (tempArray1[6]) {
            resultNumber.append(1);
        } else {
            resultNumber.append(0);
        }
        if (tempArray2[6]) {
            resultNumber.append(1);
        } else {
            resultNumber.append(0);
        }
        if (tempArray3[6]) {
            resultNumber.append(1);
        } else {
            resultNumber.append(0);
        }
        if (tempArray4[6]) {
            resultNumber.append(1);
        } else {
            resultNumber.append(0);
        }

        try {
            int resultImpl = Integer.valueOf(resultNumber.toString());
            if (resultImpl == 1100) {
                Log.e("NOTIFY", "1100");
                notificationMessage = "Input Wire 1 and 2";
            }
        } catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
            System.out.println("not number");
        }
```